# Flow type. What is the difference between type {} & {||}

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I dont know what is the exact differences.

I want to know what is the differences

Comment: Can you please at least show sample code?

Answer (score 2):

According to doc
https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types
`{||}` is a way to check for “exact” object types => no extra properties will be authorized with type with `{||}` syntax

sample from doc

```
// @flow
var foo: {| foo: string |} = { foo: "Hello", bar: "World!" }; // Error!
```

=> failed because foo can only have a foo property. Bar is unauthorized

but if you do the following it will work

```
var foo: { foo: string } = { foo: "Hello", bar: "World!" }; // Work
```

Comment: Actually, it depends on `exact_by_default` in `.flowconfig`, but since Flow 0.202 (new projects), all objects are exact by default; meaning, you don't have to use `||` anymore, but can always use `...` to allow extra properties.